# react cant resolve module when importing component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

trying to import component from components which is in src directory but it is throwing error cant find module new to react any help will be appreciated

src

```
 - app.js
 -components/create-todo.component
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import CreateTodo from './components/create-todo.component';
// import EditTodo from './components/edit-todo.component';
// import TodosList from './components/todos-list.component';

// import logo from "./logo.png";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="container">
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            {/* <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://codingthesmartway.com" target="_blank">
              <img src={logo} width="30" height="30" alt="CodingTheSmartWay.com" />
            </a> */}
            <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">MERN-Stack Todo App</Link>
            <div className="collpase navbar-collapse">
              <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li className="navbar-item">
                  <Link to="/" className="nav-link">Todos</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="navbar-item">
                  <Link to="/create" className="nav-link">Create Todo</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <br/>
         <Route path="/create" component={CreateTodo} />
  
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

create-component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class CreateTodo extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Welcome to Create Todo Component!!</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the file `create-todo.components` have a `.js` file extension?

Comment: @JayKariesch yes it is Js file

Comment: I don't think having a '.' in a file name would cause any good to your code. Also, check if you have a default export and the export name is exactly the same as your component name.

Comment: @KrisztianNagy added create component code i think it has to do with the way i am importing  figuring out that

Answer (score 1):

Try switching the file extension from `.component.js` to `.jsx`.

So the file would be called `create-todo.jsx` and your import would look like this:

```
import CreateTodo from './components/create-todo';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an *s* on the directory you're trying to import from:

`import CreateTodo from './components/create-todo.component';`

Should be:

`import CreateTodo from './components/create-todo.components';`

If this doesn't work, could you please clarify your directory structure? It goes `src/components/create-todo.components`?

Comment: `src/components/create-todo.component` dont have `s` at the i dont think it matters but yes thats how my directory structure is , still not working